# Supplying a stream to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I know I can convert an array of images stored on my hard drive (if numbered correctly) using these arguments:

```
-f image2 -r 10 -i h:\\streamin\\%05d.jpg -crf 23  -y -r 10 -f ogg -
```

Is there a provision in ffmpeg to change this bit:

```
h:\\streamin\\%05d.jpg
```

To a stream of images stored as a memory stream at all?

i.e.: stdin = 'memorystream of images'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input images are all JPEGs, one after another, but you don't have a pattern to read from, you need the `mjpeg` demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i - -r 10 -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -f ogg -
```

This assumes that whatever you pipe to ffmpeg is what ffmpeg would output as `mjpeg`. If that doesn't work (sorry, can't try at the moment), you could also try:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -c:v mjpeg -i - …
```

**Important:** `ogg` as an output format, without further options, implies libtheora as an encoder, which does not have the `-crf` option. libtheora uses `-q:v` with a range of 0–10, where 10 is the highest quality. 7 should be a good value. If you don't use `-q:v` it will fall back to 200 kbit/s, which would result in bad quality.

Comment: Very good answer. Out of interest can the output be specified to a web page ie:  -f ogg http://myurl/acceptbinarydata.aspx ? - thanks

Comment: In theory, yeah. `ffmpeg` has the [`http` protocol](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#http) where you can output to HTTP, but I'm totally honest, I have no idea how to configure this. Usually you'd stream with the UDP protocol in a local network, so you could use `udp://hostname:port` to send UDP data there. If you haven't already, you can also try asking on the ffmpeg mailing list.

Comment: Thank you - everything works. If I could give you 2 green ticks I would!

Comment: thanks. Whilst I am on a roll - and pls dont spend any time on this - but is it possible to receive the ogg stream on the server side and extract the images from it or does the ogg stream need to be closed 1st?

Comment: You would need a dedicated streaming container, such as MPEG transport streams. Those could be parsed on the fly. Ogg files are meant to be read as a complete file.

Comment: Hi, that answered my question- thanks.  Alternatively, then instead of extracting images from a video file to the hard drive could i extract directly into stream?  The ogg would be uploaded every 20 frames (eg).  At the moment using '-i - -qscale 1 h:\\out\\img-%05d.jpg' but would like to do this '-i - -qscale 1 -' which does not work